# Does anyone know any applications of CW-complexes in graph theory?

Tags: graph-theory, gt.geometric-topology, cw-complexes

As *everyone* knows :P, a graph is a CW-complex of dimension 1. Knowing that, are there any interesting results in graph theory that arise from working with CW-complexes? And more specifically, in algorithms / computability?

Comment: What kind of results are you thinking about? The question is rather broad. Also, consider adding a major tag (those starting with two letters and a dot).

Comment: I imagine something as "Hey, I'd like to know whether this graph has this X propery....wait! Seeing it as a CW-complex, it's much easier!"

Comment: So I guess things like the hom-complexes used to study colorability are not what you are interested in? You only want to consider the graphs themselves as topological spaces?

Comment: That sounds like something I'd be interested to read about, thanks. Are you talking about this? [(link)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0195669808001194) ? Do you have any paper for me? Anyway, although what you say seems cool, yeah, my main interest is to see the graph as a complex and see what I can obtain from that

Comment: Configuration spaces in graphs are related to motion-planning problems and they are natural CW-complexes associated to graphs.